# comma separated string comparison in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to search countries from a table as given below:

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | country     
+-----+-------------+
| 1   | US          
+-----+-------------+
| 2   | US,IN,UK
| 3   | US,NZ
| 4   | AUS
```

How I perform sql query to get all records containing a country = 'US' with additional comma separated countries?
Thanks

Comment: Please check your spelling before posting questions.

Comment: @Martin Bean, Thank you so much for your advice. I will keep it in my mind wherever I will post any question

Comment: What is the type of the `country` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FIND_IN_SET function, for example -

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('US', country) ;
```

Comment: in inner join conditions
SELECT * 
        FROM 
         table1 t1
            INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.id, t1.column2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use FIND_IN_SET function, for example -

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('US', country) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, country
FROM yourtable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('US', country)
```

or

```
SELECT id, country
FROM yourtable
WHERE CONCAT(',', country, ',') LIKE '%,US,%'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67a26/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('US', country) > 0
```

- [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `LIKE` or `RLIKE` for this.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE country RLIKE '(.+?,)*?US(,.+?)*'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE country LIKE '%US%'
```

First query avoids retrieval of ones with country having US as substring like `RUS`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE country RLIKE '(.+,)(.+,)*?US(,.+)*|(.+,)*?US(,.+)(,.+)*'
```

selects only those with at least another entry along with US.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
SELECT ID,COUNTRY FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COUNTRY LIKE '%US%;
```